# Using code nuggets for setting controls properties

Tags: asp.net

Why cant i use code nuggets to set a control property??For example a validationgroup of a button or the text property of a label.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="test" ValidationGroup='<% =TestValidate %>'

<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<% =Test %>' />
```

Is there any way to set a controls properties without using codebehind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use data binding:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# "Hello World" %>' />
```

provided that you call [DataBind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.databind.aspx) in code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm....this is actually a good idea, but this time i think ill stick with the code behind after all.:) 
10x a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

`<%=SomeVar %>` uses late binding which behaves like a Response.Write (in Page.PreRender, if I remember correctly). Hence it will not be utilized by the server controls like the way you wanted it. Unless you use code-behind or inline-code-behind to perform binding.